# Результат умножения на маску

Tags: java

Помогите пожалуйста раскурить маски:

Если я умножаю большое число на маленькую маску (предположим число имеет 32 символа в двоичной системе) а маска всего 2, то я получу результат умножения 1х двух символов исходного числа на маску? всё остальное не входит в результат?

Я миею ввиду &

Comment: Если речь идёт о битовых операциях, вас должно интересовать не умножение, а конъюнкция и дизъюнкция (которые `&` и `|`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё просто. Для конъюнкции маска задаёт те биты, которые вам «интересны», остальные будут обнулены.

Пример:

```
Number   1101 0110 1011 1001
Mask     0000 0000 1111 0011
----------------------------
Result   0000 0000 1011 0001
```

Старшие восемь бит результата (или младшие, в зависимости от [порядка битов в байте](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#.22Bit_endianness.22)) нулевые, так как отсутствуют в маске; следующие 4 бита скопированы в результат, из последних четырёх в результат «просочились» только 2 младших бита.

Comment: Спасибо. обнаружил в результате это и решил спросить для ясности)